# How to change the table structure Cart page in Custom Magento Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, phtml

I have a custom magento theme installed on magento 1.9.0.1 version called meigee Black and white theme. The cart page table structure is all wrong and I have turned on path hints and tried to change the corresponding phtml file, cart.phtml and default.phtml yet Im not able to re arrange it despite changing the table structure.

[image]

Comment: can you share your cart.phtml code?

Comment: or rename cart.phtml to cart-new.phtml and check again it is working fine or not

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the hint again, then there is an empty hint before the datatable, that is the location of the file that holds the table.

in my case `frontend/mytheme/mytheme_child/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

bust at the moment cant really describe it with pictures, but let me know whats up.

Answer (score 0):

To change the table structure cart page in custom Magento make few structural changes. Make sure you have finalized the look. Once the look is finalized change the width of the product column, change the text and select box sizes on the shipping location module. This will help you change the table structure page and will allow you to make the required changes.